# Compression issue using 7zip in powershell

Tags: powershell, zip, powershell-2.0, 7zip

I made a powershell script to look into the folders and convert all text files that are 30 days old into zip files. However, I am getting 2 errors:

1: The code works fine if there is just 1 folder containing files, incase of multiple folders, it gives a wrong output.

2: I need a zip file for every file which is 30 days old, viz a.log, b.log and c.log should be converted as a.zip, b.zip, c.zip.

Also after the operation is over, the old log files should be deleted. Here is my code, please help me on this:

```
$Pathname="G:\7za920\test"

$folders = (Get-ChildItem -Path $pathname | 
             Where-Object {$_.Attributes -eq "Directory"} | 
              Select Fullname).Fullname

Foreach ($folder in $folders){
  $files = Get-ChildItem -Path "$folder" | 
    Where{$_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)}

    Foreach ($file in $files){
       ./7za.exe a -tzip archive.zip $file.FullName     
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the "wrong" output you are observing?

Comment: Your $folders array will only contain folders within your $Pathname directory because Get-ChildItem will not recursively find folders in subdirectorys unless you specify the -Recurse option

Comment: You will need to replace archive.zip with the name of the file specific zip archive names you want.